# JQUERY - Enviar valor selecionado para o valor do input

Tags: javascript, jquery

eu tenho seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#search").keyup(function() {
            var pesquisa = $(this).val();
            if (pesquisa != '') {
                document.getElementById('search-results').style.display = 'block';
                var dados = {
                    palavra: pesquisa
                }
                $.get('../search/search-inst.php', dados, function(retorna) {
                    $(".search-results").html(retorna);
                });
            }
            if (pesquisa == '') {
                document.getElementById('search-results').style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="GET" action="../search/search.php">
    <input class="ws-search-input" type="text" size="30" maxlength="35" name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="Pessoas, Empresas, Vagas">
    <input class="ws-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
</form>

<ul class="search-results" id="search-results">
</ul>
```

É uma função que vai mostrando o resultado conforme a pessoa escreve no input. Eu preciso saber como eu faço para quando a pessoa clicar em um dos resultados enviar o valor da opção escolhida para o input?

O meu PHP é:

```
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    echo '<div class="show-results">';  
    $photoid = $res['userid'];
    $photogender = $res['gender'];
    $requestfilename = "../_profile_image/$photoid.jpg";
    $photodefaultm = "../_profile_image/default-m.jpg";
    $photodefaultf = "../_profile_image/default-f.jpg";

    if (file_exists($requestfilename)) {echo "<img src=\"$requestfilename\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" style=\"border-radius:2px;\">";} elseif($photogender=="Feminino"){echo "<img                             src=\"$photodefaultf\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" style=\"border-radius:2px;\">";} elseif($photogender=="Masculino"){echo "<img src=\"$photodefaultm\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\"               style=\"border-radius:2px;\">";}

    echo '<form>';
    echo '<input class="search-profile-submit" type="submit" value="visitar perfil">';
    echo '</form>';


    echo '<p class="searchinst-name">'.$res['firstname'].' '.$res['lastname'].'</p>';


    $searchcity = $res['city'];
    $searchstate = $res['state'];

    if($searchcity != 'selecione' AND $searchstate != 'selecione') {echo "<p class=\"searchinst-city\">$searchcity / $searchstate</p>";}




    echo '</div>';



}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54633/discussion-on-question-by-rhundler-jquery-enviar-valor-selecionado-para-o-valo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se percebi bem a tua questão estás a receber HTML via ajax para dentro de , e o HTML tem este aspeto:

```
<p class="searchinst-name">algo aqui</p>
```

Para inserires esse "algo aqui" no input precisas de ter um auscultador de eventos delegado, uma vez que o HTML é dinamico.

Podes usar assim:

```
$('#search-results').on('click', '.show-results', function() {
    var texto = $(this).find('.searchinst-name').text();
    $('#search').val(texto);
});
```

---

#### Nota:

fazer

```
echo '<form>';
echo '<input class="search-profile-submit" type="submit" value="visitar perfil">';
echo '</form>';
```

para dentro de um `<ul>` é errado. Erro de sintaxe e de semântica.

Comment: Nesta solução que você passou, o input #search recebe o valor do que está em .searchinst-name. Teria como passar esse mesmo valor mas quando clicar na div com class = show-results? Eu apenas alterei de .searchinst-name para .show-results mas ele passa todos os valores dentro da div para o input. Teria como fazer isso?

Comment: @rhundler mas `.show-results` vai ter vários resultados certo? Queres que ele apanhe todas as palavras, é isso?

Comment: Então.. tem vários resultados o problema é que colocando deste jeito que você passou a pessoa precisa clicar exatamente em cima do nome. Eu queria que ela pudesse clicar em cima dessa div que é o campo total dos dados e passar esse mesmo valor de antes. Tem como?

Comment: @rhundler ok. Nesse caso podes fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/kj7h77k1/

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas praticamente instantâneas. Resolvido!